# About Windows Mobile Calling status

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile-phones

My cell use Windows Mobile and I want to develop a calling software, but I don't know how about Calling status in judging.

Comment: If you mean that you want to control the baseband and make phone calls, then that will depend on precisely what phone you are trying to program to, not just Windows CE.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start reading something about Windows Mobile development:

- [Introduction to Development Tools for Windows Mobile-based Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838188.aspx)
- [An introduction to Windows Mobile development](http://www.slideshare.net/dalelane/an-introduction-to-windows-mobile-development)

The best is to have Visual Studio Professional installed and develop on it using Microsoft languages(C#, VB, C++).

If you want a free alternative, I have [CeGCC](http://cegcc.sourceforge.net/), that is a GCC(GNU C Compiler) and G++(GNU C++ Compiler) to compile Windows Mobile programs.

You can also try [FPC](http://www.freepascal.org/download.var) if you are more familiar to Pascal. Here a some suggestions of reading if you choose for Pascal:

- [WinCE port - Free Pascal wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/WinCE_port)
- [Windows CE Interface - Lazarus wiki](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Windows_CE_Interface)

Enjoy!